# Set text bold in resources (Custom font)

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have a text in my android app, I use a custom font and for each bold word in the text I want to use the Bold version of my font.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ut
>   feugiat neque. **Pellentesque** vel lorem ut tortor varius congue. In
>   **arcu** nibh, sodales quis tempus in, hendrerit sit amet ante. Nam eu massa a purus tincidunt condimentum. Integer at turpis nec elit
>   elementum rutrum. Nunc **varius** sem eu velit fermentum volutpat.

How do I do this? 
I know I can add a html tag in the resources file like this:

```
<string name="register"><b>Copyright</b></string>
```

But this uses the bold version of the default font and not of my custom font.

I use this library = https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI to set the font in xml like this

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
            android:id="@+id/edt_birthday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birthday"
            pixlui:typeface="AvenirNextCondensed_Regular.ttf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Html.fromHtml()` method with the `<strong>` tag when passing your `String`. But it means that you have to set the text of your `View` dynamically.

For example:

```
String myString = Html.fromHtml("lorem <strong>dolor sit amet</strong>");
myTextView.setText(myString);
```

It will display:

> lorem **dolor sit amet**

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set the content dynamically on TextView

First add a TextView in the layout where you need and use this code and set this String to your textview:

```
String styledText = "<font color='#000000'>" + " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ut feugiat neque." + "</font>" + "<br />" + "<b>" + "Pellentesque "+ "</b>" + "<font color='#000000'>" + "vel lorem ut tortor varius congue. In " + "</font> </small>" + "<b>" + "arcu "+ "</b>"+"<font color='#000000'>" + " nibh, sodales quis tempus in, hendrerit sit amet ante. Nam eu massa a purus tincidunt condimentum. Integer at turpis nec elit elementum rutrum. Nunc varius sem eu velit fermentum volutpat." + "</font>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));`
```